# Building UL with javascript only creates 1 li element

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists, innerhtml

I'm trying to create a list using javascript.
But my p tags will only take the value of the last p tag i defined.

This is my code https://jsfiddle.net/1Lt76jw2/
I tried adding in `lu.appendChild(li);` inbetween my p tags but that doesn't work either.

Supposed output should be

Test123

Test456

Test789

With every Test being on one p tag each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create new *p* and *li* element for each individual element:

```js
myUL = document.getElementById("myUL");
var ul = document.createElement('ul');
var li = document.createElement('li');
var p = document.createElement('p');

p.innerHTML = "Test123";
li.appendChild(p);
ul.appendChild(li);

p = document.createElement('p');
p.innerHTML = "Test456";
li = document.createElement('li');
li.appendChild(p);
ul.appendChild(li);


p = document.createElement('p');
p.innerHTML = "Test789";
li = document.createElement('li');
li.appendChild(p);
ul.appendChild(li);

myUL.appendChild(ul);
```

```html
<div id="myUL">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You create only one `p` element and assign all your values to its `innerHTML`. Each one overwrites the previous.
Function `appendChild` does not make a copy of the element, it appends the one you originally created.